# Please revert the anchor coloring change

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface

It used to be that the main list of Questions had a clear distinction between "seen" and "not visited".  I make heavy use of that to avoid revisiting questions I have already looked at (and possibly answered).

I assume the issue is in the CSS class "question-hyperlink", where the two colors are so close that I cannot tell the difference.

Comment: The new colors are `.question-hyperlink, .answer-hyperlink { color: #0c0d0e;` (nearly black) vs `.question-hyperlink:visited, .answer-hyperlink:visited { color: #535a60;` (very dark grey). There's a difference, but you need to be looking for it *and* have good eyes.

Comment: You can fix it yourself with Stylish if you want. `@-moz-document domain("meta.stackoverflow.com") {
    .question-hyperlink, .answer-hyperlink { color: blue }
}` or whatever color floats your boat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions by @CertainPerformance, I discovered the Chrome Extension `NoSquint Plus` which provides a simple interface for changing the color of visited and non-visited links.  (A minor drawback:  It changes the coloring of all links on all pages in the site.)