# Undoing recent CSS tweaks

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, ios

Is it just me? I view the Stack Overflow website on my iPhone. A recent update modified the CSS content so all texts/links are the same colour, regardless of whether or not I've previously visited that link.

Can we just have a "Yikes, this is terrible. Revert! Revert!" button?

Comment: Normal mode, dark mode or system setting? I assume on the iPhone only Safari is the browser of choice? Does the iPhone or Safari have a version number? That might be handy to know in case this fixes itself in an update of the OS/Browser.

Comment: @rene I'm viewing the 'Mobile' version as opposed to 'Full Site' version - I don't think the 'Mobile' version has a Dark Mode - but I do view in dark mode on my PC.

Comment: @ΛRYΛN op is viewing thru phone

Comment: @Strawberry the old mobile view I don;t think is maintained much anymore (with new features or updates that aren't bug fixes).  They are putting everything into the responsive view.  I would be surprised if they actually did anything to change it recently.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I can only report my experience

Comment: Happens to me too. All post titles are black. Not as nice as previous one.

Comment: This isn't new. Links have been the same color for years now (or at least so close that I cannot readily distinguish them on any of my screens). See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392188/please-revert-the-anchor-coloring-change I have a userscript that corrects this by [injecting some CSS](https://github.com/codygray/so-userscripts/blob/master/Prolix.user.js#L105).

Comment: I think it's not just SO. Here is the bug report on Meta SE: [Post links colouring seems broken on mobile web](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357588/756727) which as of now is marked as "status-review": "*ah, today we shipped a change that introduced css variables, and that's where we probably broke it. We'll take a look, def not intended.*"

Comment: @ginomempin yep, that looks like it. Good to know I'm not going nuts (at least on the evidence presented thus far)

Comment: This is not specific to mobile (or even Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange?). I follow [this protocol](https://superuser.com/questions/638250/how-can-i-change-link-colors-in-firefox-and-chrome-but-leave-all-other-colors-a/638257#638257) for Firefox (it can be tricky to get to work).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I think we've established that it's specific to SE.

Comment: As of 14 hours ago, this has now been resolved (although the blue seems a shade lighter than I remember)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 14 hours ago, this has now been fixed. :-)

Comment: Ah, when I first commented above, I had misunderstood that you were talking specifically about the "mobile web" site (which is almost entirely ignored by the developers and not something that I use). Now that I know that... [this bug report from MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357588/post-links-colouring-seems-broken-on-mobile-web) is precisely a match for what you were seeing, and explains when and how the problem was resolved.